# function pointers query

Tags: c, function-pointers

what is the difference between these two below:

```
typedef void (*my_destructor)(void *);

typedef void (*my_destructor)(void *)  my_func_ptr;
```

is the second one valid?

Comment: What does your compiler say when you compile it?  What do you think it should do?

Answer (score 7):

The first one declares a type called `my_destructor`. This type is a pointer to a function taking a parameter of type `void*` and returning nothing.

The second one is not valid, what are you trying to do ? If you want to declare a variable of type `my_destructor`, you have to do this:

```
typedef void (*my_destructor)(void *);
my_destructor my_func_ptr;
```

Comment: Or just `void (*my_func_ptr)(void*);`, if you want to declare a variable of that type without naming the type. But really you should name function-pointer types, because it's a lot of error-prone hassle to keep repeating them in full all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a type for a pointer function.
The first one is the good one it mean you have a type named my_destructor who is a pointer to a function `(*my_destructor)` that take a void pointer `(void *)` on arguments and who return nothing (`void`).

Now you can use your type as if it was another type like for example char, long or whatever.